# Read selected line from text file using Shell

Tags: shell, sed

I have written this code, wanting to sieve out selected line from seating.txt. But it doesn't seem to work. Please help!

```
echo `sed -n "/$NUM/p" seating.txt`
```

File as followed:

```
29;,A2,A3,A1,E2,B1,B2,C1,C3,C2,D1,D2,D3,E1,E3,A4,E4,B3,B4,C4,D4
29;,A1,A2,A3,A4,B2,E4,C3,B3,D3,D2,E1,E2,C2,B4,C4,D4,C1,D1,E3,B1
43;,A2,D4,C3,B3,A4,E4
44;,A1,D4,E2,C3,A2
44;,A1,B2,C3,D4,A4
```

Comment: no obvious need for echo \` sed ... \`, just `sed -n ...`. good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a line containing $NUM then it's:

```
grep "$NUM" file
```

If you want a line with exactly $NUM before the first semi-colon it's:

```
grep "^$NUM;" file
```

If you want line number $NUM then it's:

```
awk -v num="$NUM" 'NR==num' file
```

If you want something else, tells us what and post some expected output to go with the sample input you posted.

Comment: Pardon my question, but what does NR stands for?

Comment: **N**umber of **R**ecords read so far across all input files.

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish exactly. If you're trying to print lines where `$NUM` occurs, your code works fine:

```
NUM=29
sed -n "/^$NUM/p" file
```

Results:

```
29;,A2,A3,A1,E2,B1,B2,C1,C3,C2,D1,D2,D3,E1,E3,A4,E4,B3,B4,C4,D4
29;,A1,A2,A3,A4,B2,E4,C3,B3,D3,D2,E1,E2,C2,B4,C4,D4,C1,D1,E3,B1
```

If you're trying trying to pass a line number, try:

```
NUM=4
sed -n "$NUM{p}" file
```

Results:

```
44;,A1,D4,E2,C3,A2
```